# How secure are session attributes in Spring MVC apllication?

Tags: spring, rest, jsp, authentication, spring-security

Let's say I have a Spring MVC application with JSP pages. Also, I have another application, which is RESTful web service(based on Spring too) that supports token auth.

I'm getting data from rest service by using jQuery ajax. Is that a good idea to get auth token from REST service, put it in session and then use it in JSP pages?  I mean, get it via EL like that `${sessionScope.myToken}` and put into ajax request header. Are there any flaws in using this approach?

Comment: Please can you try to lay out your question so that it is clearly readable?

Comment: No, it isn't secure. You should not convey the auth-token to the client. You should configure single-signon at the server end to both applications.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the answer! But it's still not clear to me how is it possible to sign in to the REST service once and have access to it for some time without sending any user's data later. REST service is supposed to be stateless, so you need to provide some credentials with each request, don't you?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. The HTTP session should take care of that, for as long as it exists.